# Why does the SSM decoding vary between different A429 label types

Tags: avionics, arinc-429

For A429 there are different label types, for example: BCD, BNR, Discrete...
These types have their corresponding SSM (Sign/Status Matrix) that is unique, for example an SSM of "00" represents a failure for BNR but represents a normal operation for a Discrete.

Could someone explain why is that the case? Why not just have a the same SSM interpretation for both Discrete and BNR?

I looked online for an answer but to no avail.

Thank you